# i'm saving real time data on an array List but when trying to display them i have to refresh my page for each new value

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm about to develop an android application that display real time data received from IBM Watson on a line chart 
So I'm saving the received data on an array List but when I'm trying to display them I have to refresh my page for each new value

any solution for that Please !

Comment: which chart library are you using?

Comment: MPAndroid chart

Comment: MPAndroid does not support real time data, so you will have to call `mLineChart.invalidate();` whenever you add new data in order for it to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask in background to receive data in DoInBackground. It has built in methods and ProgressUpdate will update your UI without refreshing the page.